# inserting rows by using insert and values and subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I really would appreciate your help.

I have three tables "Dossiers" in "Dossiers_CheckList"
"CheckList_Parms"
I created an insert triger Effective
when I add the row to the table "Dossiers" I want to insert lines in "Dossiers_CheckList" carrying value "Dossiers.id" ​​the new recording and "Dossiers_CheckList.id" ​​wearing a critaire
  here is the triger:

```
BEGIN
 declare @id1 int
 select @id1=id from inserted

insert into Dossiers_CheckList
(DOS_id ,CheckListParm_id)
VALUES 
(@id1
,
(SELECT CheckListParms.id
 from CheckListParms
 where CheckListParms.DOC_IS_OBLIG=1
 )
)

END
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot insert with 'values' and 'Select' at the same time, but you can reference your variable in your select statement.

```
BEGIN
 declare @id1 int
 select @id1=id from inserted

insert into Dossiers_CheckList
(DOS_id ,CheckListParm_id)

SELECT @id1,CheckListParms.id
 from CheckListParms
 where CheckListParms.DOC_IS_OBLIG=1



END
```

Be careful that you ensure your trigger handles a situation where multiple rows are inserted